# Retrieve line from ValidationDate Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have difficulties to write a SQL script.

I have a table like this:

[image]

And I want to have a result like this:

[image]

I used the `min` and `max` functions but that doesn't work.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you for your help

Comment: "I have"/"I want" isn't a question. Explain the transformation from input to output that you are trying to achieve, show your attempt and explain what isn't working. We can help you fix it if we can see it. And supply data as text, not images, unless you want a picture of a query as an answer.

Comment: Also read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`MIN()` and `MAX()` do appear to get you what you want. FYI, I have converted your dates to `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourTable','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #YourTable; --SELECT * FROM #YourTable
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (
    Business_Key    int         NOT NULL,
    [Name]          varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    [Attribute]     varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    ValidFrom       date        NOT NULL,
    ValidTo         date        NOT NULL,
    Primary_Key     int         NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO #YourTable (Business_Key, [Name], Attribute, ValidFrom, ValidTo, Primary_Key)
VALUES (1, 'Toto', 'Child', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', 1)
    ,  (1, 'Toto', 'Child', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-10', 2)
    ,  (1, 'Toto', 'Man'  , '2020-01-10', '2020-01-15', 3)
    ,  (2, 'Tata', 'Woman', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', 4)
    ,  (3, 'Titi', 'Man'  , '2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', 5)
    ,  (3, 'Titi', 'Man'  , '2020-01-05', '2020-01-17', 6)

SELECT Business_Key
    , [Name]
    , [Attribute]
    , ValidFrom   = MIN(ValidFrom)
    , ValidTo     = MAX(ValidTo)
    , Primary_Key = MAX(Primary_Key)
FROM #YourTable yt
GROUP BY Business_Key, [Name], [Attribute]
```

Returns:

```plaintext
| Business_Key | Name | Attribute | ValidFrom  | ValidTo    | Primary_Key | 
|--------------|------|-----------|------------|------------|-------------| 
| 1            | Toto | Child     | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2           | 
| 1            | Toto | Man       | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-15 | 3           | 
| 2            | Tata | Woman     | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-15 | 4           | 
| 3            | Titi | Man       | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-17 | 6           |
```